# Prevent Managed Bean From Being Instantiated Multiple Times

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean

I'm new to Java so sorry if my terminology is not correct.

I have a managed bean setup (PolicyInformation) with a session scope that I instantiate in my Java code with:

```java
thisPolicy = (PolicyInformation) Utils.getSessionMapValue("policyInformationBean");
if (thisPolicy == null) {
    thisPolicy = new PolicyInformation();
}
```

The code above checks if the bean already exists, and if it does, it uses the object in the session map. It seems to work great.

However, if I add a label on my XPage to display a value from my PolicyInformation managed bean with the following code (using expression language):

`<xp:label value="#{policyInformationBean.name}"/>`

the managed bean runs twice: once when I call it in my Java class, and again when I add the label above.

Is there a way I can prevent that second call when adding the label on my XPage? Can I somehow get the value from the Java session map in my XPage label?

faces-config:

```
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>policyInformationBean</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
<managed-bean-class>com.package.PolicyInformation</managed-bean-class>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Please also show your faces-config XML file. With a managed bean you shouldn't ever have to use the 'new' keyword.

Comment: Now if you want to control the creation of your bean, which is very common and useful, then your bean would be a POJO.  The term managed bean implies that the creation is done for you.

Comment: also, look at JSF lifecycle (methods can be called multiple times) and bear in mind it is hard to make singleton in XPages (because of multiple class loaders)

Comment: I added my faces-config bean.

Comment: Do you add your manually created bean to the session scope after instantiating it?

Comment: I'm no longer using the session scope. I'm now using the view scope. I had issues with values persisting when opening up multiple documents.

Comment: To clearfiy my question: You are checking if an instance of an object exists in sessionScope (or viewScope). If it does not exist, you are creating an instance by yourself. Then, during conputation of the lable, the resolver checks if the object exists in sessionScope (or viewScope). Because you didn't added your instance to the scope, the instance is created a second time... Just creating an instance of a class does not create a managed bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider these three things:

1. Try adding an "id" property to your managed bean opening tag with the same name as your managed-bean-name. *This is likely not your problem, but this is how we set it up.*

Example:

```
<managed-bean id="dBar">
<managed-bean-name>dBar</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>eu.linqed.debugtoolbar.DebugToolbar</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 
</managed-bean>
```

2. Remove all code that creates a new PolicyInformation object. To be managed, you have to let the framework manager it all the time. I think you might be confusing it, by creating another object.
3. Alternatively, you could make this bean a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) and not a managed bean at all. This way you just create the object when you need it. You would not have an entry in faces-config anymore, and you would use the 'new' keyword when you need to create it. When the reference becomes null, then garbage collection will clean it up.

Comment: What is the benefit for adding the *id* property to the bean? Is there any use case / reason?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach.  I am unsure what benefit there is, but it was one obvious difference that I saw once the he put in his facesConfig code. I think it is worth trying, especially since it is so easy, but I would be surprised if that was the issue.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. As far as I know you can add an *id* attribute to every element you want in the *faces-config.xml*. It has no "consequences", because it has not to be unique (a name of a managed bean has to be unique by definition). That's why there is no *id* in @ManagedBean annotation.

Comment: (1) Adding an "id" property doesn't seem to prevent multiple calls. (2) How do I use values from a managed bean in other Java classes if I do not create a new object? (3) I will look into this.

Comment: Ryan, No surprise on #1.  For #2, this might help http://www.slideshare.net/RussellMaher/jmp402 starting on slide 51.  If you have 2 hrs, here is the video from IBM Connect 2013 >>http://ibmtvdemo.edgesuite.net/software/lotus/connect_2013/01-Sunday/JMP402/JMP402.html.  Based on what you shared, #3 seems like your best solution.

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please accept.  Feel free to ask new followup questions as new questions. You will have greater visibility this way.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone at IBM, please have a look at the following Classes:

> Thread [Thread-7] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 131 in ApplicationController))
>       ApplicationController.() line: 131
>       J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Class) line: not available [native method]
>       Class.newInstance() line: 1688
>
> > **Beans**.instantiate(ClassLoader, String, BeanContext, AppletInitializer) line: 189
> >         Beans.instantiate(ClassLoader, String) line: 80 
> >         ManagedBeanFactory$1.run() line: 222
> >         AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction) line: 413
> >         **ManagedBeanFactory**.newInstance(FacesContext) line: 216
> >         ApplicationAssociate.createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans(FacesContext, String) line: 269
> >
> > > **VariableResolverImpl**.resolveVariable(FacesContext, String) line: 135 
> > >           VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(FacesContext, String) line: 71

In my opinion IBM is not able to instanciate a application, view or session scoped variable synchronized, even thought they <sarcasm> allready have </sarcasm> JAVA 1.6

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21188789 *allready wondering how long this link will work...*

Please consider race conditions as a real thing, e.g. for instanciating.

Comment: consider [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html) for further thoughts